# in training transfer learning mode getting as error module object is not collable

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, torch, transfer-learning

i was training a transfer learning model 'resnet18' using torch and i am getting this error while training it .
my torch version is = 1.5.1
i am not sure why i have to face this error i have also checked all my importing modules but still didn't find bug in that . please help :) .

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-163-eea9d0f69e32> in <module>
----> 1 model_ft, hist = train_model(model_ft, dataloaders , criterion, optimizer_ft, num_epochs=2)

<ipython-input-162-8427f4cf7832> in train_model(model, dataloaders, criterion, optimizer, num_epochs, is_inception)
     22 
     23             # Iterate over data.
---> 24             for inputs, labels in dataloaders[phase]:
     25                 # inputs = inputs.to(device)
     26                 # labels = labels.to(device)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py in __next__(self)
    343 
    344     def __next__(self):
--> 345         data = self._next_data()
    346         self._num_yielded += 1
    347         if self._dataset_kind == _DatasetKind.Iterable and \

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py in _next_data(self)
    383     def _next_data(self):
    384         index = self._next_index()  # may raise StopIteration
--> 385         data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
    386         if self._pin_memory:
    387             data = _utils.pin_memory.pin_memory(data)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\fetch.py in fetch(self, possibly_batched_index)
     42     def fetch(self, possibly_batched_index):
     43         if self.auto_collation:
---> 44             data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
     45         else:
     46             data = self.dataset[possibly_batched_index]

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\fetch.py in <listcomp>(.0)
     42     def fetch(self, possibly_batched_index):
     43         if self.auto_collation:
---> 44             data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
     45         else:
     46             data = self.dataset[possibly_batched_index]

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torchvision\datasets\folder.py in __getitem__(self, index)
    135         sample = self.loader(path)
    136         if self.transform is not None:
--> 137             sample = self.transform(sample)
    138         if self.target_transform is not None:
    139             target = self.target_transform(target)

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

this is my training function

```
def train_model(model, dataloaders, criterion, optimizer, num_epochs=25, is_inception=False):
    since = time.time()

    val_acc_history = []

    best_model_wts = copy.deepcopy(model.state_dict())
    best_acc = 0.0

    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        print('Epoch {}/{}'.format(epoch, num_epochs - 1))
        print('-' * 10)

        # Each epoch has a training and validation phase
        for phase in ['train', 'val']:
            if phase == 'train':
                model.train()  # Set model to training mode
            else:
                model.eval()   # Set model to evaluate mode

            running_loss = 0.0
            running_corrects = 0

            # Iterate over data.
            for inputs, labels in dataloaders[phase]:
                # inputs = inputs.to(device)
                # labels = labels.to(device)

                # zero the parameter gradients
                optimizer.zero_grad()

                # forward
                # track history if only in train
                with torch.set_grad_enabled(phase == 'train'):
                    # Get model outputs and calculate loss
                    # Special case for inception because in training it has an auxiliary output. In train
                    #   mode we calculate the loss by summing the final output and the auxiliary output
                    #   but in testing we only consider the final output.
                    if is_inception and phase == 'train':
                        # From https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-optimize-inception-model-with-auxiliary-classifiers/7958
                        outputs, aux_outputs = model(inputs)
                        loss1 = criterion(outputs, labels)
                        loss2 = criterion(aux_outputs, labels)
                        loss = loss1 + 0.4*loss2
                    else:
                        outputs = model(inputs)
                        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)

                    _, preds = torch.max(outputs, 1)

                    # backward + optimize only if in training phase
                    if phase == 'train':
                        loss.backward()
                        optimizer.step()

                # statistics
                running_loss += loss.item() * inputs.size(0)
                running_corrects += torch.sum(preds == labels.data)

            epoch_loss = running_loss / len(dataloaders[phase].dataset)
            epoch_acc = running_corrects.double() / len(dataloaders[phase].dataset)

            print('{} Loss: {:.4f} Acc: {:.4f}'.format(phase, epoch_loss, epoch_acc))

            # deep copy the model
            if phase == 'val' and epoch_acc > best_acc:
                best_acc = epoch_acc
                best_model_wts = copy.deepcopy(model.state_dict())
            if phase == 'val':
                val_acc_history.append(epoch_acc)

        print()

    time_elapsed = time.time() - since
    print('Training complete in {:.0f}m {:.0f}s'.format(time_elapsed // 60, time_elapsed % 60))
    print('Best val Acc: {:4f}'.format(best_acc))

    # load best model weights
    model.load_state_dict(best_model_wts)
    return model, val_acc_history
```

i thought it was because of calling transforms object just by importing its module but it didn't worked out .

```
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
```

thanks in advance .

Comment: Please, update with the code used to define `dataloaders`.

Comment: It says that there's some error in your Dataset/Dataloader class. We need the class definition to find out the cause of the exact error.